# How do I post a comment in a discussion thread?

Tags: support, comments

User help: I am relatively new to this forum.  This site currently grants me the capability to provide an answer to any posted question, however, I do not see a feature enabling me to add a comment to a thread of dialogue.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to both Mi Yodeya and meta!  [Commenting (anywhere)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) requires 50 reputation, so you're halfway there -- ask or answer a few more questions and you'll get there.  But you can always comment on your own posts, for example to respond to comments from others.

(I am not sure why the reputation threshold is different for comments than for answers.)